# Can anyone gelp me add a yes or no in my function alert box please

Tags: php

here is my function:

```
function alert($msg)
{
    echo "<script>alert('$msg');history.back();</script>";
}
```

and this is how i call the function:

```
if (statement is true)
{
  Update the query!
}
}else{ alert("Please enter numeric in age");echo formupdateadd2 ();}
```

Comment: My best guess is that you need to read this: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/476) Though it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Would you say a "confirm" alert box ? This is like an alert box but with 2 buttons yes/no and a way to get the result as is:

```
if (confirm("do you want it ?")) 
{
    // if they clicked yes
}
else
{
    // if they clicked no
}
```

Comment: Off topic: *if they clicked yes*: "It's yours, my friend. As long as you have enough rupees."